# How to set default fill value for sparse data frame after removal of pd.SpraseDataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, sparse-matrix, default-value

In the past it was pssible to do

```
pd.SparseDataFrame(some_sparse_matrix, default_fill_value=some_value)
```

This will be removed:

> FutureWarning: SparseDataFrame is deprecated and will be removed in a
>   future version. Use a regular DataFrame whose columns are SparseArrays
>   instead.
>
> See
>   http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/sparse.html#migrating
>   for more.

The help page for migrating code  says:

> The `SparseDataFrame.default_kind` and `SparseDataFrame.default_fill_value` attributes have no replacement.

So, what is the best way to define a default fill value on the future?